# Is it possible to only request the metadata?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, httpwebrequest

I'm developing a small application in C# to change the background image with images from the web.

Since I would like to avoid unused requests as much as possible, I would like to know if it's possible to request just the contenttype (and the image size) without actually downloading the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of a `GET` request, you should try to use a `HEAD` request.

[Live demo](http://web-sniffer.net/).